# In Typescript, how to import json and dynamically lookup by key?

Tags: typescript

In typescript 3.0.3, I import a json file like this:

```
import postalCodes from '../PostalCodes.json';
```

It has this format:

```
{
    "555": { "code": 555, "city": "Scanning", "isPoBox": true },
    "800": { "code": 800, "city": "Høje Taastrup", "isPoBox": true },
    "877": { "code": 877, "city": "København C", "isPoBox": true },
    "892": { "code": 892, "city": "Sjælland USF P", "isPoBox": true },
    "893": { "code": 893, "city": "Sjælland USF B", "isPoBox": true },
    "897": { "code": 897, "city": "eBrevsprækken", "isPoBox": true },
    "899": { "code": 899, "city": "Kommuneservice", "isPoBox": true },
    "900": { "code": 900, "city": "København C", "isPoBox": true },
    "910": { "code": 910, "city": "København C", "isPoBox": true },
    "917": { "code": 917, "city": "Københavns Pakkecenter", "isPoBox": true },

... and so on
```

I want to use it like this:

```
// first.postalCode is of type string
const x = postalCodes[first.postalCode];
```

I get the error: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '...very long type signature...' has no index signature."

Is there a way to get this working with the automatically generated json types, so that I can look up a postal code by it's string key dynamically?

My best approach right now is to have an intermediary ts file like:

```
import postalCodes from './PostalCodes.json';

export const PostalCodesLookup = postalCodes as {
    [key: string]: { code: number, city: string, isPoBox: boolean }
};
```

Comment: What output are you exactly expecting? Do you want to return `{ "code": 555, "city": "Scanning", "isPoBox": true }` when your input is "555"? If this is the case you might want to use Object.keys() and using these values access the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your main issue here is not that the compiler needs to infer the type of `postalCodes` in some different way, but that `first.postalCode` is not known to be one of the keys of `postalCodes`.    Since `first.postalCode` is of type `string`, it is reasonable for the compiler to warn you about this.

So you need to do some kind of [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) to convince the compiler to narrow `first.postalCode` from `string` to `keyof typeof postalCodes`.  I don't think any of the builtin control-flow type guards will do this sort of narrowing for you (`first.postalCode in postalCodes` does [act as a type guard](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256) in some cases but only to narrow the type of `postalCodes`, which is not what you want.)  Luckily you can implement a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
function isKeyof<T extends object>(obj: T, possibleKey: keyof any): possibleKey is keyof T {
  return possibleKey in obj;
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
declare const first: {postalCode: string};
if (isKeyof(postalCodes, first.postalCode)) {
  const x = postalCodes[first.postalCode];  // no error  
} else {
  // uh oh, first.postalCode is not valid
}
```

Note that you do have to handle the case where `first.postalCode` is not one of the keys of `postalCodes`, which is something you really should do, if all you know about `first.postalCode` is that it's a `string`.

Caveat: `isKeyOf(obj, key)` is not fully type safe in general.  It's possible in TypeScript for a value `obj` to have more properties than the compiler knows about in `keyof typeof obj`.  That is, types are not [exact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  In the most extreme example, if `obj` is declared as type `{}`, then `keyof typeof obj` is `never`, despite the fact that `obj` may well have properties.  This is why the [common request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24243#issuecomment-390106568) to have `Object.keys(obj)` return `Array<keyof typeof obj`> is always [rejected](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208).

Luckily for us, this caveat is *not* an issue for object literals with inferred types like `postalCodes`.  That's because you know for sure that `typeof postalCodes` is exact; there are no extra properties to worry about.  in general it's not safe to narrow `key` to `keyof typeof obj`, as shown by

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Since TypeScript v2.9 you can enable `resolveJsonModule`flag in `compilerOprions` of your **tsconfig.json** file like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... other options
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
}
```

Now TypeScript should automatically resolve the types in your imported json file.

To work around the index type issue, I could suggest two options:

1. Enable `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` in your **tsconfig.json**. This will suppress this error message. You won't get any type hints either.
2. Create some types for the JSON, and use those instead of just `string`:

   ```
   import codes from '../codes.json';
   type PostalCode = keyof typeof codes;

   const goodSring: string = '555';
   const badString: string = '2';
   const goodCode: PostalCode = '555';
   const badCode: PostalCode = '2'; // Error:(39, 7) TS2322: Type '"2"' is not assignable to type '"555" | "800" | "877" | "892" | "893" | "897" | "899" | "900" | "910" | "917"'.
   const array: [] = [];
   const obj = {some: 'prop'};
   const num: number = 123;

   const list: PostalCode[] = [
       '555',
       '2', // Error:(43, 5) TS2322: Type '"2"' is not assignable to type '"555" | "800" | "877" | "892" | "893" | "897" | "899" | "900" | "910" | "917"'.
       goodCode,
       badCode,
       goodSring, // Error:(46, 5) TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"555" | "800" | "877" | "892" | "893" | "897" | "899" | "900" | "910" | "917"'.
       badString, // Error:(47, 5) TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"555" | "800" | "877" | "892" | "893" | "897" | "899" | "900" | "910" | "917"'.
       goodSring as PostalCode,
       badString as PostalCode, // no protection here

       array as PostalCode, // Error:(54, 13) TS2352: Conversion of type '[]' to type '"555" | "800" | "877" | "892" | "893" | "897" | "899" | "900" | "910" | "917"' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Type '[]' is not comparable to type '"917"'.
       num as PostalCode, // Error:(55, 13) TS2352: Conversion of type 'number' to type '"555" | "800" | "877" | "892" | "893" | "897" | "899" | "900" | "910" | "917"' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
       obj as PostalCode, // Error:(56, 13) TS2352: Conversion of type '{ some: string; }' to type '"555" | "800" | "877" | "892" | "893" | "897" | "899" | "900" | "910" | "917"' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. Type '{ some: string; }' is not comparable to type '"917"'.
   ];
   ```

   Depending on how "hard-coded" the usage will be, exporting the `PostalCode` type could work out well for you.

   You could also write a function that checks against the JSON at run-time:

   ```
   import codes from '../codes.json';
   export type PostalCode = keyof typeof codes;

   function verifyCode(s: string): s is PostalCode {
       return codes[s as PostalCode] !== undefined; // or use Object.keys, or some other method
   }

   let city: string;
   const str: string = 'asd';

   if (verifyCode(str)) {
       city = codes[str].city; // in this branch `str` is `PostalCode`
   } else {
       city = codes[str].city; // complains about the index signature
   }
   ```

[image: Typed Autocompletion example]

Comment: Thanks, but I already use that option. It's when I do that, that I get the error.

Comment: @asgerhallas Sorry, I certainly rushed into this without thinking about it harder. I have updated the answer with certain things that might help you. In the end, the "ideal" way you is just not there, so you will have to decide on which trade-offs fit your case better.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up and the useful suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

As of late, you could also use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) with JSON files.

Something like this:

```ts
const postalCodes: { [key: string]: { code: number, city: string, isPoBox: boolean } } = await import('../PostalCodes.json');
const x = postalCodes[first.postalCode]; // should work just fine here now
```

or using explicit interface or type declarations (which I would prefer):

```ts
interface PostalCodes {
  [key: string]: { code: number, city: string, isPoBox: boolean }
}

const postalCodes: PostalCodes = await import('../PostalCodes.json');
const x = postalCodes[first.postalCode]; // should work just fine here now
```

In addition to setting the `resolveJsonModule` compiler option to `true`, you should use a supported value for the `module` compiler option as well. At the time of writing this answer, dynamic imports in TypeScript seem to be supported for module types `es2020`, `esnext`, `commonjs`, `amd`, `system`, or `umd`.